# What "it" refers to here?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

> The mind is essentially survival machine.  Attack and defense against other minds, gathering,  storing,  and analyzing information – this is what it is good at, but **it** is not at all creative.  All true artists create from a place of no mind, from inner stillness.

What  **it** refers to here?
The mind, or what it is good at?

Comment: "it" refers to the mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" refers to "mind":

The author is claiming that "the mind is good at storing and analysing information, but the mind is not creative"